# Unclear about notation in Generating Set Definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I am unclear about the notation used in the Abstract Algebra notes given by Alex Hulpke, where he [defines](https://www.math.colostate.edu/%7Ehulpke/lectures/m366/generated.pdf) a generating set as follows.

Let $G$ be a group and let $a_1, a_2, ... a_n \in G$. The set $\langle a_1, a_2, ... a_n\rangle= \{ b_1~^1 \cdot b_2~^2 ..... b_k~^k \mid k \in N_0= \{0,1,2,3... \}, b_i \in \{a_1, ... ,a_n \},~ _i\in {-1, 1}  \} $.

I cannot understand what the $i$ is supposed to correspond to? The exponents are $1,2,... k$ as well as the subscripts. Is there a way to salvage the notation used in the definition or fix it up. Maybe by introducing more variable letters like $j$.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it seems like a letter didn’t print. What they mean is
$$
\langle a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\rangle = \{ b_1^{\varepsilon_1} \cdot b_2^{\varepsilon_2} \cdots b_k^{\varepsilon_k} \mid k \in \mathbb{N}_0, b_i \in \{ a_1, \dots, a_n \}, \varepsilon_i \in \{1, -1\} \}
$$
(where the $i$ in the brackets implicitly runs over $\{1, \dots, k\}$).

Essentially, the generated group consists of any product of any number of elements of $\{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$ and their inverses (where elements can be repeated).

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check. That would explain the spacing as well (for the exponents).